# Integrate a country code picker in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, spinner, mobile-country-code

I have to integrate a country code spinner for mobile registration in Xamarin. I have inserted all country names successfully in spinner but I also want to add flags and codes with country names.

[image]

Please provide me the best way to add country name with flags and codes in Spinner. I want C# code.

Comment: Xamarin has nothing to do with Marine, i think.

Comment: What do you mean by spinner. Wouldn't a dropdown be enough here?

Comment: Why not picker? https://blog.xamarin.com/new-bindable-picker-control-for-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Forms there is not a ComboBox (your image seems to be a ComboBox...). You can use a Picker like @Alex suggests. Otherwise you can create a Popup Page with a ListView. There is a good plugin with samples

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Those are some methods

```
// Use these methods in PopupNavigation globally or Navigation in your pages

// Open new PopupPage
Task PushAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.PushPopupAsync

// Hide last PopupPage
Task PopAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopPopupAsync

// Hide all PopupPage with animations
Task PopAllAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync

// Remove one popup page in stack
Task RemovePageAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.RemovePopupPageAsync
```